# Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. \"File\r\n\"

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, c-sharp

I am trying to edit an existing page with this code. When I am setting a publishComment it is throwing this exception.

```
item["Title"] = pageTitle;
item["PublishingPageContent"] = pageContent;
item.Update();
SharePointTools.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
item.File.Publish(publishComment);
SharePointTools.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

What am I doing wrong? I need your help guys.

Comment: Are you sure that none of the objects (pageTitle, pageContent, publishComment) is null?

Comment: yes all has a value